# Change view controller on tableView touch using an external class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am developing an iOS App using Swift and I was wondering to know how to change view controller when the user touches a cell. I googled a lot but I could not find anything.

My code:

```
class ViewControllerMain: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let customTableView = CustomTableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.customTableView.tableData = ["item 1", "item 2", "item3"]
        self.tableView.delegate = self.customTableView
        self.tableView.dataSource = self.customTableView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

And then:

```
class CustomTableView: UITableViewController {

    // I omitted a lot of overrides that are not useful for this question.

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        // Here I would like to redirect the user to another view controller, let's say "ExampleViewController".

    }

}
```

Is there a way to specify in `ViewControllerMain` the view controller that has to be displayed if a cell is touched? If not, how can I redirect the user directly from `CustomTableView`? Thanks.

Comment: Side note - `CustomTableView` should not extend `UITableViewController`. It should conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Why did you make `CustomTableView` the delegate if you want `ViewControllerMain` to make the decisions?

Comment: @rmaddy How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the controller CustomTableView the data source and the delegate for its view.  That means moving the model for your table view, an array: `["item 1", "item 2", "item3"]`, to the table view controller, `CustomTableView`. (Also, I renamed it; a controller shouldn't be named "...View".):

```
class CustomTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {
let examples = ["item 1", "item 2", "item3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let exampleViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AstoryboardSceneID")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(exampleViewController!, animated: true)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return examples.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let example = examples[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = example

        return cell
    }
```

You'll have to set the identifier in Interface Builder as shown below:

[image: Setting view controller identifier]

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier 'pushOrPresentViewController'`, how can I solve?

Comment: I tried and I must put `exampleViewController!`, otherwise I get an error. When I run that code it gives no error but doesn't push the exampleViewController. How can I solve?

Comment: I edited my answer to define the data model `["item 1", "item 2", "item3"]` as a property of the UITableViewController that controls the UITableView. So, I recommend you try at first with only two view controllers and once you get the simplified version working, it's easier to add complexity.